# Spanning Trees: Prove if $e_1$ is an edge in $X$ that isn't in $Y$, then there exists an edge ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Say $X$ and $Y$ are two different spanning trees of a simple and connected and undirected graph $G$. Prove that if $e_1$ is an edge in $X$ that isn't in $Y$, then there exists an edge $e_2$ in $Y$ that isn't in $X$... so the graph $(X − e_1) + e_2$ (obtained from $X$ on replacing $e_1$ by $e_2$) is also a spanning tree of the original graph, $G$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Upon removing $e_1$, the graph $X-e_1$ is disconnected into two components, $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Think of the edges of $Y$, must there be one that connects a vertex in $T_1$ and a vertex in $T_2$?

Comment: How do we know that removing an edge from X results in cycle components?

Comment: I use $C_i$ to denote component, not cycle components.... perhaps let me change the notaiton to $T_i$.

Comment: I see! Thanks. As for your question, we don't necessarily know that an edge $e_2$ that isn't in X will connect $T_1$ and $T_2$, do we?

Comment: but do we know an $e_2$ that is in $Y$, ($Y$ is a spanning tree) will connect $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: I want to say yes. But I am confused as to why.

Comment: Suppose that there is no such $e_2$, then $Y$ can't connect $T_1$ and $T_2$, hence it is not connected. So it can't be a spanning tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63819/discussion-between-chester-and-siong-thye-goh).