# $T=T_1-f_1+f_2$ is a spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $T_i=(V,F_i),i=1,2$ spanning trees in $G$ with $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset.$ Let $f_1\in F_1$. Prove that there is $f_2\in F_2$ such that $T:=T_1-f_1+f_2$ is a spanning tree.
My idea:
Let $f_1\in F_1$. Because of $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$ there exists $f_2\in F_2\backslash F_1$ so that adding $f_2$ to $F_1$ yields a cycle in $T_1$ containing $f_1$ and $f_2$.  So if we remove $f_1$,  $T=T_1-f_1+f_2$ is connected with $|V|-1$ edges and is a spanning tree. Is my idea correct?

Comment: Right track, but I'm not convinced yet that "*Because of $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$ there exists $f_2\in F_2\backslash F_1$ so that adding $f_2$ to $F_1$ yields a cycle in $T_1$ containing $f_1$ and $f_2$.*" What if every $f_2 \in F_2$ I could choose creates a cycle that does not involve $f_1$?

Comment: @TonyMathew Good point, how can I improve my proof? But I think this edge $f_2$ has to exist because of $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: One way to ensure that $f_1$ and $f_2$ lie in the same cycle is to ensure they have a common vertex

Comment: @TonyMathew they have a common vertex because $T_1,T_2$ are spanning trees, right?

Comment: In general, this is true for any two spanning trees. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392698/spanning-trees-prove-if-e-1-is-an-edge-in-x-that-isnt-in-y-then-there-e